# How to reorder Laravel Nova's navigation including groups?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

How to change the order of them, just as a customer would want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You create a copy of `Laravel\Nova\Tools\ResourceManager` somewhere in you codebase.
2. You add a `"files"` key to **composer.json** under `"autoload"`

   ```
   "autoload": {
         "psr-4": {
             "App\\": "app/"
         },
         "classmap": [
             "database/seeds",
             "database/factories"
         ],
         "files": ["app/<your path>/ResourceManager.php"]
   },
   ```
3. In **ResourceManager.php** you change

   ```
   public function renderNavigation()
   {
       $request = request();
       $groups = Nova::groups($request);

       $newNavigation = collect([
           'Group1' => collect([
               Resource1::class,
               Resource2::class,
               Resource3::class,
           ]),
           'Group2' => collect([
               Resource4::class,
               Resource5::class,
           ]),    
       ]);

       return view('nova::resources.navigation', [
           'navigation' => $newNavigation,
           'groups' => $groups,
       ]);
   }
   ```